# Считать .bmp в массив данных

Tags: c++-cli

Нужно считать байты изображения(.bmp монохром) что бы потом их отправить в устройство.

Куда считать и какими средствами ?

Comment: Поправьте код под C++/CLI https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15460/C-Image-to-Byte-Array-and-Byte-Array-to-Image-Conv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public: array<byte>^ imageToByteArray(System::Drawing::Image^ imageIn)
{
 MemoryStream^ ms = gcnew MemoryStream();
 imageIn->Save(ms,System::Drawing::Imaging::ImageFormat::Bmp);
 return  ms->ToArray();
}
```