# Конвертировать массив байт в Bitmap для отображения в picturebox

Tags: c++-cli

Подскажите как переконвертировать массив байт в Bitmap?

```
    public: array<Byte>^ imageToByteArray(System::Drawing::Image^ imageIn)
 {

             MemoryStream^ ms = gcnew MemoryStream();
             int t = 0;

             imageIn->Save(ms, System::Drawing::Imaging::ImageFormat::Bmp);
             ArrayTemp = ms->ToArray();
}
```

В массив был конвертирован так

Comment: Это зависит от того, как Bitmap был переконвертирован в массив байт.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov добавил конвертацию в массив

Comment: Это вообще что? Какой-то кусок некомпилируемого кода. Сложно было грамотно [скопипастить](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/818106/184217)? (Впрочем, там тоже опечатка).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Image^ ConvertToImage(array<Byte>^ bytes)
{
    MemoryStream^ stream = gcnew MemoryStream(bytes);
    Image^ image = Image::FromStream(stream);
    return image;
}
```

По правде говоря, тут ещё нужна обработка исключений и правильная очистка ресурсов (как и в вашем коде конвертации изображения в массив байтов). В C# это делается легко и приятно, но мазохисты выбирают C++/CLI. Как это правильно сделать? Например, смотрите [здесь](https://deviorel.wordpress.com/2015/01/15/automatic-disposal-of-resources-in-ccli-and-c/).