# Замена битов в байтах (двойная плотность пикселей)

Tags: c++-cli

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Имеется массив байт (Конвертированый BMP) в котором нужно проверять биты 
если бит=1 то следующий тоже=1 если бит=0 то следующий=0 
как реализовать такой цикл ?

Comment: Мне вопрос не понятен. Нужно каждый чётный бит установить в такое же значение, как и нечётный? Или изменить bpp - bit per pixel - вместо одного сделать два?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov добавлю просто картинку что бы было понятно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по вашим предыдущим вопросам, вы работаете с массивом байтов, полученным из изображений типа `System.Drawing.Image`, `System.Drawing.Bitmap`.

Как вариант, можно обойтись возможностями самой GDI+.

Допустим, имеется картинка с исходным изображением:

```
Bitmap source = new Bitmap("source.bmp");
```

Следующая строка кода создаст новую картинку, увеличенную вдвое (растянутую) по горизонтали. Вроде, именно это вам и нужно.

```
Bitmap target = new Bitmap(source, source.Width * 2, source.Height);
```

Всё! Можно её использовать. Например, сохранить:

```
target.Save("target.bmp", ImageFormat.Bmp); // выберите желаемый формат
```

Код на C#. Думаю, перевести на C++/CLI не составит труда.

---

Другой вариант, отрисовка через `Graphics`. У этого класса есть множество свойств, можно поиграться с их настройкой для получения нужного качества.

```
Bitmap target = new Bitmap(source.Width * 2, source.Height); // создаем пустое изображение

var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(target);
//graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
//graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
graphics.DrawImage(source, new Rectangle(0, 0, target.Width, target.Height));
```

---

И напоследок, кардинальный способ. Использовать метод [LockBits](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/5ey6h79d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

В примере кода по ссылке показано, как скопировать изображение в массив байтов и работать с ним в цикле. Это будет быстрее, чем копирование через `MemoryStream`. К тому же, в массиве будет именно сырая пиксельная карта, без *шапки* и т. п.

Answer (score 0):

Надо понимать что бит 1 мы заменяем на 11 т.е. число 3. Если нет, то 0. 10=> 1100 = 12, но 12/2 = 6. Таким образом можно распаковать биты. abcdefg => aabbccddeeffgg

Реализация в с++ где-то так...

```
 unsigned short* doubledensity(char* a, int size){
      unsigned short* q = (unsigned short*)malloc(size*2); // или другим способом получить массив назначения
      for (int i=0;i<size;i++)
         q[i]=(a[i]&1)*3+(a[i]&2)*6+(a[i]&4)*12 +(a[i]&8)*24 +(a[i]&16)*48+(a[i]&32)*96+(a[i]&64)*192+(a[i]&128)*384;
      return q;
      }
```

Не забудте q освободить. Если бит был один - стало два - то массив q должен быть в два раза больше размеров. Если q будет массив char или int - прийдётся кастить в short (при таком способе) иначе не правильно посчитает (или прийдётся менять механизм записи в q). Желательно не ошибится с кастом.

a - это имеется ввиду массив с чистым изображением, без шапок, без выравниваний.

Comment: У автора с шапкой и т. п. [тыц](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/818094/184217)

Comment: Шапка легко вытаскивается так как с ней есть указатель на начало пиксельного массива

Comment: Тут показано само расжатие пиксельного массива. Думаю пиксельный массив сами получите.